# Command Completed Successfully is displayed instead of result as grid while executing a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

Command Completed Successfully is displayed instead of result as grid while executing a stored procedure. It should actually show me some data

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogReport]
@dtFromDateTime datetime,
@dtToDateTime datetime
AS
BEGIN
if (@dtFromDateTime!=null and @dtToDateTime!=null)
begin
    select EncryptionLogID,concat(FirstName,' ',LastName) as Username, ClientName,ProjectName,Purpose,Type,StringToConvert,InsertDateTime
    from EncryptionLogs
    inner join Users on Users.UserId=EncryptionLogs.UserID
    where cast(InsertDateTime as date) between cast(@dtFromDatetime as date) and cast(@dtToDateTime as date)
end
else if (@dtFromDateTime=null and @dtToDateTime!=null)
begin
    select EncryptionLogID,concat(FirstName,' ',LastName) as Username, ClientName,ProjectName,Purpose,Type,StringToConvert,InsertDateTime
    from EncryptionLogs
    inner join Users on Users.UserId=EncryptionLogs.UserID
    where cast(InsertDateTime as date)=cast(@dtToDateTime as date)
end
END
go
```

so when i use EXEC LogReport  'value1','value2'
note: yes i have to pass the date as null sometimes from a filter (From date and To date )

Comment: You have a typo.  You don't use `= null` and `!= null`.  The correct operators are `is null` and `is not null`.  I consider this a typographical error and vote to close.

Comment: In SQL, NULL means UNKNOWN and *all* comparisons with an unknown value produce the only logical result - UNKNOWN. This means that both conditions fail and no query is executed

Comment: yes now it is working fine. very helpful...thank you Gordon for the perfect solution and Panagiotis for knowledge